# Bedeutung von "aufs + Adjektiv"

Tags: meaning

Welche Bedeutung hat die Kombination aus "auf" und einem Adjektiv?
Beispiel:

> Er kritisiert die Regierung aufs Schärfste.
>
> Dieser Bericht wird nur dazu benutzt, den Kapitalismus aufs massivste schlechtzureden.

Weitere Beispiele:

> aufs Deutlichste sagen;
>   aufs Dringlichste flehen;
>   aufs Eindringlichste warnen;
>   aufs Einfachste
>   aufs Eingehendste
>   aufs Engste befreundet sein;
>   aufs Entschiedendste
>   aufs Genaueste
>   aufs Gröbste
>   aufs Herzlichste 
>   aufs Höchste 
>   aufs Schärfste
>   aufs Strengste 
>   aufs Tiefste

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Die in deinen Beispielen verwendete Adjektivform des Superlativs in einer adverbialen Konstruktion nennt man auch *[Elativ](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elativ)*, die maximal mögliche Steigerung der Eigenschaft.

Sie wird verwendet, wenn man den Superlativ nicht vergleichend ("Frankreich verurteilte den Raketenstart scharf, China schärfer und die USA am schärfsten"), sondern absolut ("Die USA verurteilten den Start aufs Schärfste") meint (In deinen Beispielen wird ja auch nichts genannt, womit man vergleichen könnte).

Etwas "aufs Schärfste" verurteilen bedeutet damit, dass man es "so extrem wie irgend möglich" verurteilt.

Elative hat man gerne in Arbeitszeugnissen: "... zu unserer vollsten Zufriedenheit ..."

Englisch kennt den Elativ nur noch in einigen Wendungen, z.B.

> to enjoy something to the fullest

Answer (score 2):

*»aufs«* (oder auch *»auf das«*) plus Adjektivform beschreibt ein besonders ausgeprägtes Ausmaß.

> - etwas aufs Schärfste kritisieren = etwas sehr scharf kritisieren
> - etwas auf das Deutlichste sagen = etwas sehr deutlich sagen

Beispiel aus dem [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/auf_Praeposition):

> jemanden auf das / aufs Herzlichste, (auch:) herzlichste (*sehr herzlich*) begrüßen